# Java Swing open new content in same window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm a student javadevelopment in Brussels. 
The focus of the course lies on backend and webapp's, now we're currently covering spring(core, enterprise and mvc, we going to skip security and messaging).

I would like to be able to create graphic stand alone app's to, so I started a side project in swing, for a non-profit historical organisation I want to wright a app that connect's with a local database and let's them manage their members and the libary. Secondary there's going to be a webapp that lets de websitevisitors search the libary for availability and reserve the items.

I started with the adminapp (to manage members and the libary).
It starts with a simple userloginform a textfield user, a other password and a loginbutton. On click it's stores the username and password and should open a other JPanel in the same frame, that's bassicly how the user is going to navigate through the app. 
When I click the loginbutton a new empty frame opens (what it shouldn't), when I maximize my new frame and minimalize it again, my old frame is showing what it's supposed to. 
I know the way I call my second Jpanel is not the most elegant way, but I had no pre knolledge of swing starting this, I just started experimenting and puzzled bits and piece together on the internet.

Anyway, this is the nullpointer exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at  com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLayoutManager.addLayoutComponent
(GridLayoutManager.java:134)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1127)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:417)
at be.kokw.views.MainApp$1.actionPerformed(MainApp.java:48)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed
(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed
(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased
(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl
.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl
.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.
doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters
(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter
(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy
(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

My MainClass:

```
public class MainApp{
private JButton login;
private JPanel panel1;

private JLabel labelForUser;
private JTextField userField;
private JLabel labelForPassword;
private JTextField passwordField;
private String user;
private String password;
static JFrame frame = new JFrame("KokwApp");

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}


public MainApp() {

    login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        /**
         * Invoked when an action occurs.
         *
         * @param e
         */
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            user = userField.getText();
            password = passwordField.getText();
            DbSelection db = new DbSelection();
            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            frame.getContentPane().add(db.getPanel1());
            frame.repaint();



        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame.setContentPane(new MainApp().panel1);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

I asked my teacher today...
His answer: I don't like to use swing. Read up on javafx... Lol

So any tips on what's wrong would be welcome.
Just to be exact I use intelij.
Finally, sorry for my crappy gramar, but as I said in the beginning, I'm Belgian

Comment: `getPanel` from `DbSelection` is likely returning a `null` value

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah I did, I forgot to mention I use a guiform. I printed user and password, just to see if they got storted and they did...

Comment: @Izuro What do you mean that db.Getpanel returns null? It should return the Jpanel I use in DbSelection (which is bassicly the same class, with a other guiform and no main.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: speaks the truth. Look at the answers in the duplicate used to close this question to gain the general heuristic on how to debug NPE's. You'll see them again and again, and so you need to know this process well.

Comment: @Izuro I checked db.getPanel for null, didn't take care of the exception and the nullcondition never get's executed, so...